# How would comparison cause numerical overflow when using System.nanoTime()

Tags: java, android

I found the following guide in the android documentation of [System.nanoTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

> one should use t1 - t0 < 0, not t1 < t0, because of the possibility of numerical overflow.

And I am really curious how comparison would cause an overflow. As to my knowledge overflow occurs when we are close to the highest representation and the resulting computation results in even higher value than can be achieved.

Comment: What part of ['differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately 292 years (263 nanoseconds) will not correctly compute elapsed time due to numerical overflow'](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) didn't you understand?

Comment: I see. So long as I use this within the span of 292 years comparison is fine?

Comment: But given the statement you referred, how would subtracting solve the problem - that comparison wouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the overflow does not happen in the comparison but in the clock values, once every 2^63 nanoseconds cycle, and this can happen at any time  because the origin it arbitrarily fixed (for a given virtual machine)

```
// say the clock value happens to be Long.MAX_VALUE - 10
long ts1 = 9223372036854775797L;

// 100 ns later it has overflowed (it is now negative)
long ts2 = ts1 + 100;

System.out.println("ts2 - ts1 > 0 : " + (ts2 - ts1 > 0));
System.out.println("ts2 > ts1 : " + (ts2 > ts1));
```

The result is :

```
ts2 - ts1 > 0 : true
ts2 > ts1 : false  <-- not correct
```

Comment: outputting ts2 gives -9223372036854775719. I didn't know when a positive long value overflows it becomes negative. I thought it would be just infinity or something like that.  Then when we do subtraction again... it becomes positive. it is all weird. but thanks. I never knew.